# Restrict Access to Domain Admin/Admin Group for all

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a pretty old setup which was managed by our client. They could manage anymore and they have outsourced the entire Datacentre to us.
Everything is messed up right now. Nothing in place correctly and i have taken in charge of it to.

Its a 5000-10000 User, 5 Forest with single domain each environment ( Yes 5 forests root domain). The company kept acquiring other companies and instead of making it a child domain, every company acquired has been made as a forest and forest trust is created among them.

Every tom, dick or harry is having the access to the Domain Admin. Even a service desk guy has been added to the Domain Admin or other sensitive groups.

First and the foremost thing i thought of making changes to the environment is to restrict the access of unwanted people to the DC and other servers and to give least access required to perform their work.

How can i start achieving this. Need your help/suggestions as how should i plan to go ahead.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: There's no such thing as a multiple forest root domain. Do you mean that there are 5 forests each with a forest trust to each of the other forests?

Comment: Before you start revoking existing privileges get management buy in; people will complain. Loudly and frequently. Your problem sounds primarily an organisational one and typically you can't use IT to fix the organisation.

Comment: The sceptic in me says: in the short term as an outsourcing provider you'll probably make almost as much and have a much happier client if you simply maintain what they have rather than by running a big technical improvement program. If you still want to go that route, organise and charge that as a separate project and ensure that your client has real tangible benefits as well and not just your IT department benefits... Because cleaning up a big mess is always painful.